# How to get tokens for noune phrases in spaCy?

Tags: python, spacy

I get the tokens and noun phrases with

```
text = ("This is commonly referred to as global warming or climate change.")
doc = nlp(text)

for token in doc:
    print(token.i, token.text)

print("Noun phrases:", [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
```

and the result is

```
0 This
1 is
2 commonly
3 referred
4 to
5 as
6 global
7 warming
8 or
9 climate
10 change
11 .
Noun phrases: ['global warming', 'climate change']
```

is it possible to get the index of tokens for noun phrases instead of the words? For example

```
Noun phrases: ['6,7', '9,10']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [`Span`'s `start` and `end`](https://spacy.io/api/span) properties:

```
start   int     The index of the first token of the span.
end     int     The index of the first token after the span.
```

So, use

```
print("Noun phrases:", [(chunk.start,chunk.end-1) for chunk in doc.noun_chunks])
# => Noun phrases: [(6, 7), (9, 10)]
```

Or, if you need comma-separated string items,

```
 ["{},{}".format(chunk.start,chunk.end-1) for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]
 ## => Noun phrases: ['6,7', '9,10']
```